# Down-leg Counting in mlm in php

Tags: php, sql

I am coding for mlm software in php. But I faced a problem while calculating down-leg members and their commission. Calculation of my script is perfect upto maximum 100 users .But when users are more then 100 then browser show error message 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\xxxxxxxxxx\index.php on line 171
here is my code

```
    $sql = "Select * from members WHERE ID='123'";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {

            echo getView($row['UID'],$dbh);
    }   

function getView($arUID,$dbh)
    {
        global $cnt;
        $sql = "Select * from members WHERE UNID='$arUID' order by ID";
            foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
                {
                    $cnt++;
                    echo getView($row['UID'],$dbh);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Try to set `max_execution_time` to 120 in your `php.ini` or in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: when i used "max_execution_time" then count upto 200 records

Comment: which type of table format You are using if you can show then i can help u..